# Extend Windows partition using gparted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, gparted

[image]

I use dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10. I want to resize the windows partition `(/dev/sda4)` by shrink space from Ubuntu partition `(/dev/sda1)` and add this space to Windows

I boot gparted using USB and i can shrink space from ubuntu partition, but i can't use this unallocated space.

How i can move the Microsoft reserved partition , to increase windows partition space ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete and recreate it (with the same 'msftres' flag). This partition is nothing else than a 16 MiB *space reservation* – any data it contains is irrelevant.

Comment: the Microsoft Reserved Partition stores the Windows bootloader files. Windows will not boot if this partition is deleted

Comment: It doesn't. They're stored in the "EFI System Partition" in your screenshot. (On BIOS systems, the bootloader files are stored in an NTFS partition of similar size to the EFI partition, whose _NTFS label_ happens to say "System Reserved" while it has no relationship to the partition that you currently have.)

Comment: The [MSR partition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/design/dn640535(v=vs.85)#what-is-a-microsoft-reserved-partition-msr) is used with GPT to support software components that formerly used hidden sectors and technically doesn't need to exist, although Microsoft recommends it _(many OEMs don't create it)_